# Filling treeview with data from related database tables

Tags: c#

When compiling the code, errors of two types come out; here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SqlConnection con;
    bool a = true;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    DataTable dt, dt2, dt3;
    TreeNode macroNode, superNode, objektNode;
    string CmdString, macroCode, superCode, objekCode, macroName, superName, objektName;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            cn.ConnectionString = Form1.MyConnectionString;
            cn.Open();
            LoadData();
        }
    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(Form1.MyConnectionString);
        CmdString = "SELECT МакроКод, макрообъект FROM ВыборМакроОбъект";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(Form1.MyConnectionString, con);
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            macroCode = dt.Rows[i]["МакроКод"].ToString();
            macroName = dt.Rows[i]["макрообъект"].ToString();

            macroNode = new TreeNode(macroName, macroCode);

            CmdString = "SELECT Код, суперкод FROM State WHERE макрообъект=@МакроКод AND СуперКод!=5";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@МакроКод", macroCode);
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt2 = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(dt2);

            for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                superCode = dt2.Rows[j]["СуперКод"].ToString();
                superName = dt2.Rows[j]["суперобъект"].ToString();

                superNode = new TreeNode(superName, superCode);

                macroNode.ChildNodes.Add(superNode);

                CmdString = "SELECT ОбъектКод, объект FROM ВыборОбъект WHERE суперобъект=@СуперКод";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@СуперКод", superCode);
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt3 = new DataTable();

                sda.Fill(dt3);

                for (int k = 0; k < dt3.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    objekCode = dt3.Rows[k]["ОбъектКод"].ToString();
                    objektName = dt3.Rows[k]["объект"].ToString();

                    objektNode = new TreeNode(objektName, objekCode);

                    superNode.ChildNodes.Add(objektNode);
                }
            }
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(macroNode);
        }
    }
}
}
```

1. in lines like: `superNode = new TreeNode (superName, superCode);`

> error "Argument 2: Cannot convert from" string "to" System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode [] ""

2. in lines like:
   `macroNode.ChildNodes.Add (superNode);`

> error "" TreeNode "does not contain a definition for" ChildNodes "and could not find an available extension method" ChildNodes "that takes the type" TreeNode "as the first argument (possibly missing a using directive or assembly reference)."

Answer (score 0):

1. You are passing two string-valued parameters to the TreeNode constructor (superName, superCode), and it is expecting a string and a TreeNode array. Review the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.-ctor?view=net-5.0
2. There is no property named "ChildNodes" in TreeNodes. I believe the property you mean to invoke is TreeNodes.Nodes, and to add values you would need to invoke its Insert() method.

Comment: Thank you! More details about treenode.node?